# Why MSFT Earnings Release FY18 Q4 is missing in the SEC filings?

Tags: historical-data, sec, annual-report, quarterly-report

I was checking the validity of the data of some fundamental data provider and used MSFT as an example. I was surprised that it doesn't have the latest MSFT Earnings Release for FY18 Q4.

The published report on the Microsoft site [Earnings Report](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Investor/earnings/FY-2018-Q4/press-release-webcast) - note the date July 19, 2018.

I asked support and they answered that their data is exactly the same as [SEC filings](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?CIK=MSFT&owner=exclude&action=getcompany&Find=Search) - I checked the SEC fillings  and indeed it doesn't have that report either.

So, my question is, am I right and there's a huge delay (more than a month) before Earnings Release will be put in the SEC filings? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Q4 ended on June 30th and the [10-K was published on Aug 3](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459018019062/0001564590-18-019062-index.htm).  The delay was only a couple days more than a month.  However, some of the information was available in the [July 19 8-K](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000119312518221458/d501766dex991.htm).

Comment: Looks like the 2017 annual report was published around the same timeframe (Aug 2).